# What is Intellij telling me with this green background color on certain variables?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

[image]

On `user` and `asset` I'm getting this green background. What is it? I'm not in "highlight ocurrences" mode, as I pressed ESC.

Hovering gives type (is an interface).

This is typescript code.

What I checked:

- it is not "Identifier under caret"
- it is not "Injected language fragment"

Answer (score 6):

Found the solution [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004366939-2019-2-Narrowed-to-string).

It was the "Variable type narrowed by a type guard" setting in

```bash
Settings 
  -> Editor 
  -> Color Scheme 
  -> TypeScript 
  -> "Variable type narrowed by a type guard"
```

#### What it means

the type of `asset` has been "narrowed" from type `Asset | undefined` which was returned by `getAssetFromUrl()` to then `Asset` as of the undefined check and the return.